# What's the backstory of the Emerald Herald in Dark Souls 2?

Tags: character-development, dark-souls

I was very confused when the Emerald Herald said that she was "born of dragons, (and) contrived by men".

1. Who or What is she?
2. Who created her, and for what purpose?

Comment: http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_Herald

Comment: Yes, but as with all things Dark Souls, any actual explanation by the characters themselves (as is the case in the Wiki, which is taken from her speech near the end of the game) is vague and mysterious, and we're left to find out from tiny clues. I was hoping that someone may have found out more than that.